# JavaFX. WebEngine. Ошибка при загрузке сайта

Tags: java, javafx

При загрузке сайта выскакивает ошибка

```
мая 18, 2016 5:18:18 AM com.sun.webkit.network.URLLoader doRun
WARNING: Unexpected error
java.util.zip.ZipException: incorrect header check
at java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.read(InflaterInputStream.java:164)
at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:107)
at com.sun.webkit.network.URLLoader.receiveResponse(URLLoader.java:528)
at com.sun.webkit.network.URLLoader.doRun(URLLoader.java:163)
at com.sun.webkit.network.URLLoader.lambda$run$91(URLLoader.java:128)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at com.sun.webkit.network.URLLoader.run(URLLoader.java:127)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Соответственно основная часть сайта не подгружается. Как быть?

Comment: Ну тут же видно что что-то с сжатием данных. Вы сами что-то сжимаете? Если да, то скиньте этот код.

Comment: вообще ничего не использую, передаю ссылку в webengine и при загрузке сайта ловлю эксепшн

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Перешел на библиотеку Jxbrowser и проблема пропала. Как и все недостатки вебкита javafx.